# kotlin-android-extensions in android 2023.2.1 iguana

Tags: kotlin

How do I add kotlin-android-extensions in Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-232.10300.40.2321.11567975, built on March 12, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.9+0--11185874 amd64

I didn't try anything I am new in coding

Comment: This plugin is deprecated long enough to the point of being an error, it's no longer supported and if you really need to build a project with it you need to use legacy version  of android studio.